# Remove "chat description" for NotificationOnly Bot in Microsoft Team App

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

This description is automatically shown in my Microsoft Teams App because It has a bot enabled :
[image]

> Chat with the app to ask questions and find info

However my app is using a Notification Only bot (with activity chat only) without any predefined commands neither. So, this description is confused for the clients/users since the app is not actually allowing questions or sending messages to the bot.
Here is the manifest section:

```
"bots": [
        {
            "botId": "xxx-xxx-...xxx",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": true
        }
    ],
```

Is there a way to remove that description or change it to be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way to change/remove the description, it will be shown by default.